# Editing data retrive from api inside Ember.js application

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js

I'm new to all those frameworks/js thing - so sorry if I want to do something that I'm not allowed.

I'm retrieving json data from api of another application.

In ember component I would like to display data from that json but because It can be a very long string I would like to display only first 256 characters.
I'm displaying it via {{my_model.summary}} is there a way to cut it after 256 characters so it wont break the app view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own helper as shown in [Ember Guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.9.0/templates/writing-helpers/)
or you can use an addon, for example [ember-composable-helpers](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers#slice)'s `slice` helper:

```
{{slice 0 255 my_model.summary}}
```

Comment: Looks like this is exactly what I needed. Thank you